# How to extract some characters based on certain patterns from a vector?

Tags: r, vector, text-extraction

Here are the data

```
x <- c("a01|a44;b013|b021|c35;c014|c035|c078")
y <- c("a03|a41;b033|b021|72;c014|c031|c078")
z <- c("a01|a44;c014|c035|c078;b013|b021|d35|c33")
v <- c(x, y, z)
```

I want to extract the third element separated by `"|"` from a string starting with `"b0"`. The expected result is `c35,72,d35`.

Comment: in the Z, the 3rd element of the string starting with "b0" is d35. The whole string is "b013|b021|d35|c33".

Comment: Okay, I posted a solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
sapply(strsplit(v, ';'), function(x) 
       sapply(strsplit(x[grep('^b0', x)], '[|]'), `[`,3))
 #[1] "c35" "72"  "d35"
```

Or use `sub`

```
 sub('.*;b0\\d{2}\\|[^|]+\\|([^;|]+).*', '\\1', v)
 #[1] "c35" "72"  "d35"
```